# LeetCode 124: Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem. If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

Given a non-empty binary tree, find the maximum path sum.

For this problem, a path is defined as any sequence of nodes from some starting node to any node in the tree along the parent-child connections. The path must contain at least one node and does not need to go through the root.

#### Example 1:

```
Input: [1,2,3]

       1
      / \
     2   3

Output: 6
```

#### Example 2:

```
Input: [-10,9,20,null,null,15,7]

   -10
   / \
  9  20
    /  \
   15   7

Output: 42
```

#### Inputs

```
[1,2,3]
[-10,9,20,null,null,15,7]
[-10,9,20,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,7]
[-10,9,20,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,720,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,7]
[-10,9,20,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,720,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,7999999,20,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,720,null,null,15,7,9,20,null,null,15,7]
```

#### Outputs

```
6
42
66
791
8001552
```

#### Code

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

struct Solution {
    int maxPathSum(TreeNode* root) {
        std::int_fast64_t sum = INT_FAST64_MIN;
        depthFirstSearch(root, sum);
        return sum;
    }

private:
    static std::int_fast64_t depthFirstSearch(
        const TreeNode* node,
        std::int_fast64_t& sum
    ) {

        if (!node) {
            return 0;
        }

        const std::int_fast64_t left = std::max(
                                           (std::int_fast64_t) 0,
                                           depthFirstSearch(node->left, sum)
                                       );
        const std::int_fast64_t right = std::max(
                                            (std::int_fast64_t) 0,
                                            depthFirstSearch(node->right, sum)
                                        );
        sum = std::max(sum, left + right + node->val);
        return std::max(left, right) + node->val;
    }
};
```

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/discuss/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/solution/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much to say about your answer, it looks fine! One could quibble over the names of variables, maybe `left` and `right` could be named `left_sum` and `right_sum` for example, and you could've used `auto` for the type of those two variables. But other than that I think there is nothing that can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you decided to use `std::int_fast64_t` over the common `int` that is used as the type of the tree nodes values.

But since you did, it would be more idiomatic to do at least:

```
static_cast<std::int_fast64_t>(0);
```

instead of

```
(std::int_fast64_t) 0;
```

Comment: Maybe it is better to avoid casting altogether. Casting implies you started with some different type. You can construct a zero of the proper type directly by writing: `std::int_fast64_t(0)`

Comment: Or create a named object `static constexpr std::int_fast64_t     fast_zero(0);`